# NestJS - Can't resolve queue?

Tags: nestjs

I am following [doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues) to start to use queue. I installed `@nestjs/bull`, `bull`, `@types/bull` dependencies. And here is my `app.module.ts`:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            load: [configuration],
        }),
        BullModule.registerQueue({
            name: 'create_checkin',
            redis: {
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 6379,
            },
        }),
        EventModule,
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I imported BullModule in root module. And here is my `event.service.ts`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class EventService {

    constructor(
        @InjectQueue('create_checkin') private readonly createCheckinQueue: Queue,
    ) {
    }
}
```

And when I start server, I got the following error message:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the EventService
Please make sure that the argument BullQueue_create_checkin at index [0] is available in the EventModule context.
```

I don't know which step I did wrong. Someone can help me?

Comment: Where did you provide the EventService? Can you provide more of your code?

Answer (score 13):

Had a similar problem, in my case it was enough to add the `BullModule` to the `exports` array in order to successfully run the whole project. Like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.registerQueue({ ... }),
    ...
  ],
  ...
  exports: [
    BullModule,  // <— this is important!
    ...
  ]
})
```

Then in my service I've been able to inject the queue:

```js
@InjectQueue('print') private queue: Queue<PrintJob>
```

Comment: Jiminy. Thank you for this—it’s missing from the docs and I thought I was losing my mind.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import bull module inside the module you are trying to setup queue. You can also refer https://medium.com/@shikhar01.cse14/bull-queues-in-nestjs-306c51cb0ec2

Comment: the same what I was trying to show in code above :)

Comment: Thanks, the article seems good, but there's no reference about how to create the ConfigModule or ConfigService, would be nice if the author had provided a GitHub sample repository.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are placing EventService under providers array in EventModule.

```
@Module({
     providers: [EventService],
     controllers :[],
     imports: [YOUR_MODULES],
     exports: [EventService]
})
export class EventModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing BullModule straight in Event Module - I had the same problem and doing it this way make it work.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.registerQueueAsync({
      name: 'csv',
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        redis: config.get('redis'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    CsvService
  ],
  exports: [CsvService],
})
export class CsvModule {}
```

I know that it's async method, but maybe you should try.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            load: [configuration],
        }),
        EventModule,
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        BullModule.registerQueue({
            name: 'create_checkin',
            redis: {
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 6379,
            },
        }),
    ],
})
export class EventModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the queue in `event.module.ts`, not `app.module.ts`.

`EventService` is a provider of `EventModule`, so it will have access only to objects imported into the `EventModule`.

```
// event.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [BullModule.registerQueue({...})],
  providers: [EventService]
})
```